# Как написать парсер для чата твича на java

Tags: java, парсер, twitch

Есть задача написать графический парсер чата с твича на java.
Не получается получить страницу с сообщениями.
Не выводится блок кода в котором они находятся.Хелп

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URLConnection connection = new URL("Ссылка на чат твича").openConnection();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Comment: Чат там вроде работает по IRC протоколу, так что через простой конекшн его не достать. Есть уже готовые библиотеки, вроде https://github.com/Gikkman/Java-Twirk